# Parse push notifications not received by Unity Android app in background

Tags: android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

We're using Parse for a game in Unity, and our Android app does not receive the pushes when it is on the background.

We register to "ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived" following https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes. After that, there are three scenarios:

- Good: The app is running and is in the foreground: our code catches the event "ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived" and deals with it. All good.
- Half good: The app is not running: "ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" gets the event and displays the notification. (I'd rather process it myself, but that's not the focus of this question.)
- **Bad**: The app is running, but is currently in the background (i.e. the user pressed the Home button): incoming push events are added to a queue by the Parse SDK. So, when the app goes back to foreground, we get them all at the same time. If they kill the app instead, those pushes will be lost.

Is this the expected behavior? How can we make sure we receive the events so that we can show the notifications in a timeline manner?

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing parse.com properly? A common mistake is to initialize Parse in the onCreate of a particular `Activity`, in stead of the onCreate of (a custom class inherited class from) `Application`.

Comment: That's not it, unfortunately. We're using Unity, so the initialization is a little different. And the rest of Parse works as expected